# Как отвязать репозиторий от проекта в subversion netbeans?

Tags: svn, контроль-версий, netbeans

Никак не могу отвязать репозиторий от проекта. Мне нужно заново залить проект на репозиторий, а он до сих пор помнит старые настройки удаленного репозитория и как их изменить, не могу никак понять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удалить все папки "`.svn`" или "`_svn`" во всех подпапках проекта.

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться командой `svn export` для того что бы экспортировать проект из старого хранилища.

Пример: `svn export /path/to/source-project /path/to/target-project`
После этого можно спокойно залить новый проект в другое хранилище.

Кстати можно сразу воспользоваться командой `svn import`.